# Eclipse random unknown type/resolving errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I opened up Eclipse after some time to check code for an old project. Each of my projects now have a red exclamation mark and getting error such as unresolveable and unknown data types for those imported libraries (ex: Timer, Queue, etc).

[image]

I haven't touched Eclipse in months, so I'm not sure what happened.

---

[image]

Comment: You moved your libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means Eclipse cannot find the .jar files that those libraries were inside, and now have no idea where to import them from.

To fix:

1. Right click your project and select "Properties".

   Click on "Java Build Path".

   Click the "Libraries" tab.

   Check your .jar files. It is most likely that there will be red lines under them saying "missing". Download the .jar files from the internet, and place them into a folder on your machine.

   Click "Add External JARs" and route Eclipse to this new folder

Comment: Download which jars from where?

Comment: It's this miraculous thing called google. You type what you need in there and it finds it for you!

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Timer` is part of the JRE library. If Eclipse is unable to find it, this means that the JRE system library is not being found by Eclipse.

You can view the dependency on the JRE library by right-clicking on the project and choosing **Properties -> Java Build Path**. In the **Libraries** tab there should be an entry for the JRE system library. Make sure that this is pointing to a valid JRE on your system.

If the JRE is marked unbound, check that a JRE1.6 is installed in the preferences under **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs**.

[image]

Comment: Posted image above- says it's unbound for all those projects. I never removed or unbound anything. Anyway, I tried checking that box to rebind it and it wasn't fixed.

Comment: @Growler If unbound it means that there is no JRE compatible with Java 1.6 registered in Eclipse - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Click on properties on your project context menu:

http://puu.sh/gqlBu.png

Find out which library is missing:

http://puu.sh/gqlxm.png

You can update the library's location by double-clicking on it.

Comment: I can't see anything in those images as they're too small.

Comment: Right click on them then open them in a new tab, i think they have been resized by stackoverflow.